# Array to string and replace last comma in the array (not string)

Tags: javascript

I have an array (please note that tropical and pineapple are in the same array value):

```
'apple', 'pear', 'orange', 'tropical, pineapple'
```

I wish to turn it into a string and replace the the last comma with an 'and'.

I perform:

```
fruits.join(', ');
fruits.replace(/,([^,]*)$/,'\ and$1');
```

This gives:

```
apple, pear, orange, tropical and pineapple
```

Whereas I require the last comma from the array to be replaced and not any comma in the array's values.

I'm looking for:

```
apple, pear, orange and tropical, pineapple
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Of course the pedantic answer to this question is: "Yes. It is possible." :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just don't `join` on the complete array. Instead, use

```
fruits.slice(0, -1).join(", ")+" and "+fruits[fruits.length-1];
```

If you don't need the array any more, you can also mutate it, which makes things a little easier:

```
var last = fruits.pop();
console.log(fruits.join(", ")+" and "+last);
```

Also we need to take into account the case of an empty input, so it should rather look like

```
if (fruits.length <= 1)
    return fruits.join(", ");
else
    return fruits.slice(0, -1).join(", ")+" and "+fruits[fruits.length-1];
```

which you might want to wrap in a helper function.

Comment: Might be a good idea to add a tiny bit of extra logic: `(fruits ? fruits.join(", ")+" and " : "")+last` - otherwise an array of one fruit will yield " and banana"